# iOS - navigation controller to tab bar controller

Tags: ios

In my storyboard, I have a Table View Controller and I want to be able to tap on an item in the table view and go to a detail view with more information. In the detail view, I'd like it to be like the Tab Bar Controller as the detail view can be separated into 2 categories.

Is this possible? At the moment I can do it in my storyboard, but after searching around, I can't seem to find out how to pass the details of the selected item from the Table View Controller to the Tab Bar controller.

Am I missing something obvious? Or going about this wrong? I'm new to iOS development so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you should do it programatically, way simpler in the long run than storyboards... just food for thought, but you should look into it. SB are good if you have a huge app view hierarchy but otherwise just convolute transitions IMO.

Comment: I'm thinking in the prepareForSegue method, which ViewController should I pass the data to? The one for the tab bar controller or each of the views from the tab bar controller? Or am I misunderstanding how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing the information to one of the TabBarController's view controllers in a property through the prepareForSegue method?

Create two properties in the TableView Controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourViewController *firstViewController;
```

Then Use:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);

   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegueID"]) {

       self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController*) [segue destinationViewController];
       self.firstViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
       self.firstViewController.SOMEPROPERTY = SOMEVALUE;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. When passing values through from one view to another, should you pass through an ID and then recreate the object from the ID on the other view controller, or should you pass through the object?